# How should a Gson serializer properly fail?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I'm writing some Google Gson serializers and deserializer and they look something like this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, (JsonSerializer<byte[]>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> {
    return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.toBase64String(src));
});
builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, (JsonDeserializer<byte[]>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> {
    return Base64.decode(json.getAsString());
});
```

Those are very simple, but for some others, there's a chance the serialization method will trigger an exception, but since the [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) and [JsonSerializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) didn't define their methods to raise an exception, I just cannot raise an exception.

The only two possibilities that I see is to swallow the exceptions or end the program. Am I missing a third possibility that's better than those two?

Comment: Why not throw an unchecked exception?

Comment: There would be two possibilities: the "`c`-method" of marking the output as corrupted (or returning `null`) and throwing a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just forgot the existence of unchecked exceptions (it's been a while since I was doing Java full time). Thanks.